# How to stop lsp-mode including headers automatically for C/C++ code?

Tags: lsp-mode

Every now and then lsp-mode is adding a header to the C source code I'm working on.

How can this functionality be disabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this is a bit late, but I'm also annoyed by this problem and clangd seems to have trouble working with multiple files. You can use `lsp-clients-clangd-args` to configure your clangd. Add the following:

```
(setq lsp-clients-clangd-args
    '("--header-insertion=never"))
```

For more flags, see `clangd --help`.